Symbolic logic and that which cannot be commited to language?
Imagine I have a one to many mapping function. Whatever x is it maps it to all other elements except x. So if I have x=1 then it maps it to every number except 1. Now, I claim this is nothing but the "not equals sign".
Notice by defining it relationally I can say this relation defines the "not equal sign." In this sense it doesn't matter what symbol I use. It is the relation between symbols that matter. Proceeding with this notion of symbolic manipulation some outcomes are possible: contradictory, trivial and non trivial.
Now I ask the following: are there things which will never make sense symbolic fashion? How would one prove or disprove this intuition?

"Imagine I have a one to many mapping function": then it's not a function.  --  "Some candidates are freewill and consciousness. How would one prove or disprove this claim?"  Do you have any support or at least rationale for that claim to begin with?  --  What cannot be talked about should not be talked about: wouldn't that be an answer to your question?

@JulioDiEgidio is there any discourse on what can and can't be represented symbolically?

I do think the Tractatus answers that question, but... I have raised few objections, and more for the sake of argumenting, but I am actually seeing a quite interesting question there: what symbolic even means in "symbolic logic", and how it differs from "mere" formal (which is more the "relational" part).  But I'll see if I can put together something more substantial, for now it is just some keywords dropped there, more hoping we can narrow it down...

No. Any experience can be represented symbolically.

Paradoxically we use language (gestures, signs, symbols) to evoke things that we cannot describe. Ineffable: too great or extreme to be expressed or described in words. The word "ineffable" describes in words that which we cannot describe in words. But in some sense all language is based on the internal drama or perceptions which exist in imagination independent of and alongside the gestures, signs, and symbols we use to point to our ineffable imagination.
